# coredata- relationship failing to behave properly

Tags: core-data, relationship, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

This is structure of coredata architecture. [image]

After adding entries to 'Artists', using them to newly added 'Album' entries is working perfect.

[image]

But the problem is as shown in img- 2 & 3, after assigning the 'michael jackson' to 'Insomniac 2010' album & then adding the same artist to 'Baby ft ludacris' losing the reference from the album 'Insomniac'.

This is the code where I save the context in **AlbumDetailViewController.h**

```
- (void)EntityRecordstableview:(UITableView *)tableView didselectrowatindexpath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forentity:(id)entity
{
    Artist *selectedArtist = entity;

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];

    if ([self.pickedArtists containsObject:selectedArtist]) {
        [self.pickedArtists removeObject:selectedArtist];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        editingAlbum.artist = self.pickedArtists;
        [self saveTheContext:editingAlbum.managedObjectContext];
//        NSLog(@"%d",self.pickedArtists.count);
    }
    else {
        [self.pickedArtists addObject:selectedArtist];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        editingAlbum.artist = self.pickedArtists;
        [self saveTheContext:editingAlbum.managedObjectContext];
//        NSLog(@"%d",self.pickedArtists.count);
    }
}
```

I think there must be some problem in managedObjectContext saving.
Is it should be like this

```
self.managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
[self saveTheContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

instead of

```
[self saveTheContext:editingAlbum.managedObjectContext];
```

I tried this but this is also failing to work as per expectations.

[You can find my source code here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/szz3a39y9rc4hqj/CDBestTutorial.zip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your code. Please check for the same. Their is a problem in relationship between **Artist** & **Album**. It must be Many to Many.

Your relationship between **Album** & **Artist** is 1 to many. Hence, if you will select Artist for multiple Album then it will override its value. Please check your database for same.

Code : [Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ra70d50agjhvesi/CDBestTutorial.zip)

Comment: Hey thanks bro.! Thanks for updating my code. Its like u made the fruit plate ready for me. :) Thank you very much indeed

Answer (score 1):

Every artist can have many albums, but according to the model every album can contain many artists. The to-many relation should be reversed or substituted to many-to-many type (Every album can contain many artists and every artist can have many albums)

The album - song relationship type also could be the problem later...

Comment: Hey thanks buddy. Upvoted the answer for great explanation. I will make the changes you suggested. thanks a lot.